# Proof the recurrence relation of order statistics using induction

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, sorting

I read order statistics from the book The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms", by Aho, Hopcroft, Ullman, Addison-Wesley

As per the algorithm the recurrence relation given

T(n)<= cn for n<=49 .....1

T(n)<= T(n/5) + T(3n/4) + cn for n>=50 .....2

How can I prove it by induction T(n)<= 20cn?

I have two more questions

For the 1st equation why they define n<=49 and for the 2nd equation n>=50

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is the *base case* for the recurrence. The second equation represents the *recurrence formula*, on everything that **isn't** a base case.

Now, you can prove by induction this statemen, simply by using [complete induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) as follows:

The base case is obviously correct. For the induction hypothesis, assume correctness for any $k<n$.

Now, for $T(n)$, we can use the recurrence formula to get $$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{5}\right) + T\left(\frac{3n}{4}\right) + cn$$
And notice that $\frac{n}{5},\frac{3n}{4}<n$, and hence we can use the induction hypothesis on them. Doing so, will yield:
$$T(n)\le \frac{20cn}{5}+\frac{20c\cdot 3n}{4}+cn=4cn+15cn+cn=20cn$$
And hence we also proved that $T(n)\le 20cn$ and with that we completed the induction proof.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is P(k )holds for an arbitrary integer k , need to proof that
 P (k + 1) is also true. I can not understand where do you use induction hypothesis? Additionally, T(n)<= 20cn/5+20c.3n/4+cn then, how could you make it equal to(=) 4cn+15cn+cn.

Comment: Complete induction assumes $P(k)$ for **all** $k<n$, and you will have to prove $P(n)$. For your other doubt, the equality is between $20cn/5+20c\cdot3n/4+cn$ and $4cn+15cn+cn$, its just writing a simpler form for the same value

Comment: Thanks. However as per my last question I would like to know that how could you convert inequality to equality?

Comment: Why would you want equality? The inequality is between $T(n)$ and $20cn$